# Visualization suggestion:-

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data, visualization

I have a data frame like below:-

Here I have 194 countries and the columns are fan_out values which is in percent of the total population.

Like for country AD, the total fan_out value is 2.24 -06 % of the total population.

[image]

I tried a stacked chart like below:-

The only issue is it's not presentable because the fan_out value for 5,6 or 7 is very small are not clearly seen.

Is there any way I can build a cluster to make sense of this that?

My only question is how to represent this data in one graph to make more sense like finding clusters or a pattern or even I can apply any ML algorithm to find any pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dimensional reduction algorithm like t-SNE:
https://youtu.be/wvsE8jm1GzE

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html

It is quite easy to implement and you will see correlations between countries clearly.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! I will look into it!

Comment: Can you please provide any examples! 194 countries a lot!